# c# how to show data as soon as I run the program, datagridview

Tags: c#

I hope datagridview will post the data as soon as I run the program.
By the way, I need to drag to see the information, is there a way to make it visible right away?

```
          code : 
        
           public DataTable GetEmployeesList()
                {
                    DataTable dtEmployees = new DataTable();
                    string strConn = "Server=49.50.174.201;Database=;Uid=;Pwd=;Charset=utf8";
        
                    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(strConn))
                    {
                        conn.Open();
        
                        string sql = "SELECT * FROM worker_table";
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
                        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        dtEmployees.Load(reader);
                      
                    }
        
                    return dtEmployees;
                }
        
    
this is execute time: 

      public frmAttendance()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                //  this.button4.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button4_Click); //불러오기
                //   this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click); //등록하기
    
                dataGridView1.DataSource = GetEmployeesList();
            }
```

I thought there is no error and I fix my code by stack overflow comments

Comment: What do you mean by `I need to drag to see the information`? what type of application it is? Web Application or Windows form application? The code you shared does not have any mention of DataGridView. Where this method is written? When and how is it called in the program?

Comment: Load the data into the `DataGridView` in the Form’s `Load` event.

Comment: Please add the code where you bind the data to the datagridview

Comment: I use windows form application,,! and Load event before

Answer (score 0):

the way which I use to get data is...

```cs
public DataTable GetEmployeesList()
{
   static MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=49.50.174.201;Database=;Uid=;Pwd=;Charset=utf8");
   static MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("", conn);

   DataTable dtEmployees = new DataTable();
   //open connection to database
   conn.Open();
   //sql query
   string sql = "SELECT * FROM worker_table";
   cmd.CommandText = sql;
   dtEmployees.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
   return dtEmployees;                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a datagridview1 and a datatable(dtEmployees).  In form load put -

```
Datagridview1.Datasource = dtEmployees.AsDataView();
```